# New server, can access on the LAN but not on the wider internet. No firewalls in place

Tags: networking

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server which accepts SSH and HTTP requests from another PC on the LAN but isn't accessible from the other side of my Comcast Gateway.

I have a Windows 10 PC physically connected via ethernet to the same Comcast gateway as the server, and from the Windows 10 PC I'm able to use Putty, Filezilla and Chrome (using IP address or DNS domain name in a web browser) to access the server and the website on the server. In that case through LAN, the browser on the Windows 10 PC will even redirect to HTTPS! BUT IT'S ALL A TRICK!!! Using my cell phone (using the Verizon network and not connected to LAN WiFi) I'm unable to access the server with JuiceSSH, or by using the IP address or the domain name in Chrome. DHCP or Static IP settings have no impact on access outside the LAN. Using DHCP on the server I'm still only able to access the IP address from another machine in the LAN.

I've disabled UFW.
I've disabled the Comcast Gateway firewall.

What could be wrong? How can I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there might be Network Address Translation (or NAT for short) in effect.

Is the server's IP address within one of these ranges?

- 10.0.0.0 .. 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 .. 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 .. 192.168.255.255
- 100.64.0.0 .. 100.127.255.255

If so, then you're behind a NAT: that means you can make outgoing connections just fine, but incoming connections from the Internet won't find their way to your server without some extra steps.

There is only a finite number of IP addresses, and there are not enough for all internet users to have their own public globally-routable IP address. That's why service providers usually implement NAT, to stretch their allocated address range further. (The scarcity of IP addresses is only going to get worse, and that's why IPv6 is slowly getting more and more common.)

If the IP address is within one of the first three ranges I listed, the NAT might be implemented by your Comcast Gateway, and you might be able to switch it off, so that every system in your network gets an individual public IP address. (It also means all of your systems will be getting randomly probed and attacked by worms and other malware roaming the internet, so if you go this route, make sure to keep all your systems up to date!)

Alternatively, you might be able to configure *port forwarding* in the Comcast Gateway: basically, your gateway holds a single public IP address that is shared between all of the systems connected to your Comcast Gateway. Using the settings on the Gateway, you should be able to define rules like "incoming connections from anywhere to TCP port 80 (of the shared public IP) should be routed to port 80 of **this** IP address in your local network" to allow incoming HTTP connections to work, or similarly for TCP port 22 to make SSH work. If you have UPnP and/or NAT-PMP enabled in the Gateway, some software (or devices) will be able to request temporary port forwardings automatically, without requiring you to configure them manually.

The fourth IP address range I listed is especially unfortunate: it is the new NAT range specified in [RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598) for Carrier-Grade NAT. It is most commonly used with mobile data subscriptions: in this case, the NAT is performed within the service provider's systems, and it is not configurable by the individual subscriber, so you cannot use such a subscription to handle any incoming connections at all.

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer! The IP address is indeed within the 10.x range you listed first.

I understand what has happened but now I'm confused about something else. I was able to use the certbot service on the server to setup SSL and I'm confused as to how certbot was able to work given your explanation of the issue?

Comment: Certbot apparently prefers IPv6 over IPv4, so if your connection includes globally-routable IPv6, it may have just used that instead of plain old IP.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a public IP range (highly unlikely) your internet connection is using NAT. Internal addresses are not reachable from outside (which is basically A Good Thing given the woefully weak security of widely use desktop operating systems). If you want to expose services to the internet, you need to set up port forwarding in your router.